# What does npm remove do?

Tags: npm

I'm a first time user of nodejs/npm. I wanted to uninstall reactjs from my system so I typed `npm remove reactjs@xxx`. It gave me the following. The output looked weird to me, so I search for the description of the command. To my surprise, it seems that remove is not a valid npm command.

Can someone explain what's happening here?

[image]

Comment: It seems that this command installed react-scripts on my system.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall a package

Write :

**npm uninstall 'package name '**

in your case

npm uninstall reactjs@xxx